# It's possible answer yes/no to a command on paramiko ssh?

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko

I want to automate a command using SSH, but when it run appears a message to type yes or no. Its possible answer this message in one line command or someway in paramiko.

I've tried so many things like.

```
 sudo /usr/sbin/service-maintenance-window ; yes

 sudo /usr/sbin/service-maintenance-window | yes

 yes | sudo /usr/sbin/service-maintenance-window 

 yes | sudo /usr/sbin/service-maintenance-window
```

Here is the code:

```
from paramiko import SSHClient
import paramiko     

ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())

ssh.connect("xxxx", username="xxxx", password="xxxx",timeout=5)
stdin,stdout,stderr = ssh.exec_command("yes | sudo /usr/sbin/service-maintenance-window")

print(stdout.read())
```

The message that i Want to accept is:

```
------------------------------ WARNING ---------------------------------------

You are about to be granted temporary privileged shell access of VPLEX
to perform advanced maintenance or servicing tasks.

As this shell has higher privileges, non-expert usage of this shell can
result in damage to your VPLEX as well as compromising of various
security features.

Respond Yes only if you are authorized and qualified to perform advanced
VPlex maintenance and/or servicing.

Make sure to:

1 - limit your use of this shell to only those items
that require this level of elevated privilege.    
2 - exit this elevated privilege shell when you have finished using it.

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Are you sure you want to continue ? [Yes/No]:
```

Comment: The response is read from the TTY, not stdin, so a pipe won't populate it. Since you're in Python, use pexpect.